# How do I access the members of a pointer to pointer to struct?

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management, struct

I'm trying to get more comfortable with pointers and C in general so I've been doing practice problem. I have a struct:

```
typedef struct Card
{
    enum { hearts, spades, clubs, diamonds } suit;
    int value;
} Card;
```

and a function used to allocate memory for the deck:

```
void createDeck(Card ** deck)
{
    deck = malloc(52 * sizeof(Card *)); //allocate space for deck
    if (deck == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "malloc failed\n");
        return;
    }

        //allocate memory for each card in deck
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 52; i++)
    {
        *(deck + i) = malloc(sizeof(Card));
    }
}
```

and I'm trying to use the code like this:

```
int main()
{
    Card *deck = NULL;

    createDeck(&deck);

    printf("%d", deck[0].suit)
}
```

This gives a nullptr error which makes me think I'm not allocating memory correctly. I've changed different things but I can't get this to work regardless. How do I access the members of `deck` after I've done work to it with `createDeck`?

Comment: everything in C is pass-by-value. A copy of `deck` is made when you call `createDeck`, therefore any modification made to `deck` is persistent only within the function to that copy. In order to see modifications to `deck` outside the function, you must return it or (as in this case, since you've passed a pointer), dereference the pointer and modify the object it points to (which has scope outside of the function).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me breakdown your problem.

In `main()`, `Card *deck = NULL;` will allocate a pointer to `Card` and the pointer is pointing to NULL.

Then you call `createDeck(&deck);` Here you are passing the address of the pointer to type Card. So, this address is not NULL as it is pointing to pointer variable which is allocated on stack of type Card*.

It means in `createDeck()`, the variable `deck` will not be NULL and it will be having valid address. But `*deck` which will be pointing to a pointer of type `Card*` will be NULL. You should allocate memory only for `*deck`.

```
void createDeck(Card ** deck)
{
    //deck = malloc(52 * sizeof(Card *)); //deck is a double pointer pointing to memory of type Card* allocated on stack in calling function main().
    if (deck == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Null pointer error\n"); //If calling function passes NULL, it means there is some issue.
        return;
    }
    *deck = NULL; //In more complex functions, if there are other logic before doing malloc(), it it better to reset the variables with default values.

        //allocate memory for each card in deck
    //for (size_t i = 0; i < 52; i++)
    //{
    //    *(deck + i) = malloc(sizeof(Card));
    //}

    *deck = malloc(sizeof(Card)*52); //Allocate for all 52 Cards together
    if(NULL == *deck)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "malloc failed\n");
        return;
    }

    //In case you want to access a card using deck variable.
    (*deck)[2].suit = hearts;
}
```

Comment: If I want to allocate the deck of 52 cards, I only need to use the one malloc()?

Comment: @Dumbassahedratron: Yes, this is *conceptually* equivalent to a `Card[52]` buffer, but allocated on the heap.

Comment: Yep! You're allocating space for 52 structs. The logic is the same as for allocating 10 elements for an integer array(`int *arr = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10)`) if that analogy helps.

Comment: Is `if(NULL != *deck)` correct? If I'm understanding correctly, we're doing a `malloc()` which will assign a block of memory for us, meaning it's not going to be NULL which fits the condition and will always fire that `fprintf` and `return`?

Comment: @Dumbassahedratron My mistake. I corrected it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Life will always be more simpler without `double pointers`, As far as I can see you need an `arry` of cards ( 52 ) ??

why not this ?

```
Card* createDeck( )
{
    Card *deck = malloc( 52 * sizeof(Card) );
    {
         printf("OOPS");
    }

    return deck;
}
```

and the caller

```
Card *deck = createDeck();
if( !deck )
{
   printf("Alloc Failure");
   exit(0);
}
```

Or better get rid of the `createDeck` and call `malloc` directly

```
Card *deck = malloc( 52 *  sizeof(Card));
```

---

Its a completely different proposition if you want to seethings differently
for instance a *deck is a collection of cards*

```
/* That's how a card looks like */
struct Card{
    int value;
    /* waharever else */
};

/* That's a deck */
struct deck {
   struct Card *cards;
};
```

Now Initialize a Deck

```
struct deck *createDeck( )
{
     struct deck *deck = malloc( struct deck );
     if( deck )
     {
         deck->cards = malloc( 52 * sizeof(card));
         if(deck->cards)
         {
            /* Do some thing or leavel it as is */
         }
     }

     return deck;
}
```

and the caller ..

```
struct *deck = createDeck();
if( !deck )
{
    printf("OOps memory");
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Or simply struct deck {
   struct Card cards[52];
};?